# Predict node attribute from network variables

Tags: exponential-family, networks

ERGM models the probability of a tie forming in a network. Is there a way of using ERGM, or an equivalent model, where the response variable is an attribute of the node, not a tie? Basically, turning ERGM around?

Comment: "response variable is a covariate". In statistics, response variable cannot be covariate, and covariate cannot be response variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider "SAOM" which is created by Snijders.
The SAOM model is able to predict network / node attribute simultaneously / separately.
Or just use regression model and control network dependency variable(eg. mutual, spillover...).